# How to repeatedly populate mail merge field in word document

Tags: c#, ms-word, office-interop

In the word document, I have 2 mail merge fields, firstname and lastname, they are on the same line.

Here's the code I use to populate them.

```
foreach (MailMergeField field in doc.MailMerge.Fields)
{
    if (field.Code.Text.Contains("firstname"))
    {
        field.Select();
        app.Selection.TypeText("mike");
    }
    else if (field.Code.Text.Contains("lastname"))
    {
        field.Select();
        app.Selection.TypeText("abc");
    }
}
```

Now, I need to populate them with a list of names. how do I insert mike and teresa after John?

```
john abc
mike abc
teresa abc
```

Comment: You should just execute the merge instead of trying to redo mail merge in code.

Comment: @SLaks, this is the first time I have to work with word file. Can you please elaborate? thank you.

Comment: Click Finish the Merge in the Mail Merge ribbon.

Comment: @Slaks, I updated my post. still couldn't figure it out.

Comment: Use the Mailings tab.  You need to learn the basics of Word mail merges.

Comment: @Slaks, thanks for your help.I found hte finish and merge button, but thats not what I looking for.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88617/discussion-between-qinking126-and-slaks).